# Object Variable not set error, Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I keep on getting the following error in VBA

"Object Variable or With Block Variable not set"

I have no idea why

My code is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim RNG As Range
    RNG = Sheet1.Range("C15:D55,G11,G12,G15,G18,G19")
End Sub
```

The Sheet CodeName is correct.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: A `Range` is an Object type, you need to use `Set` statement for variable assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Range` type is an `Object` type, and must be assigned to with the `Set` statement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim RNG As Range
    Set RNG = Sheet1.Range("C15:D55,G11,G12,G15,G18,G19")
End Sub
```